# Problem with custom page template and permalink

Tags: templates, frontpage

I created custom page template for news

```
template_news.php
```

with name

```
template name: news
```

and i created a page and configured for that page also i set permalink to

```
/news/%postname%
```

also i set news page for blog posts page

now WP don't use template_news.php for news page but use index.php !!
How i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set a custom homepage or custom blog page template, you should go to **Settings > Reading** and select the page you created that uses your custom page template:

[image: Screenshot of settings]